# Facebook authorisation iOS Crashing

Tags: ios, facebook

App crashes when logging on facebook.
Open it for the first time works fine but as soon as you login on facebook 
it crashes. The authorisation is successful but then it crashes and throws the following exception:

```
2016-01-26 03:20:35.909 VIT Foody[43064:1911291] {
    id = 10204157645941939;
    name = "Supreet Singh";
}
2016-01-26 03:20:35.914 VIT Foody[43064:1911291] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ecd2885 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010e74bdf1 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ecd27bd +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010eccb06e -[__NSCFArray removeObjectAtIndex:] + 94
    4   VIT Foody                           0x000000010e03a90f -[TrendingController choose] + 719
    5   VIT Foody                           0x000000010e039f31 -[TrendingController viewDidLoad] + 1361
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010f41bd65 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 860
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010f41c0b4 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010f47870d -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 502
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010f477a67 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] + 59
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010f473810 -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 377
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010f473686 -[UITabBarController setSelectedViewController:] + 234
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010f33aa1c +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 65
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010f46f727 -[UITabBarController _selectDefaultViewControllerIfNecessaryWithAppearanceTransitions:] + 344
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010f470711 -[UITabBarController viewWillAppear:] + 195
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010f4215cc -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 710
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010f421c6e -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 149
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010f45cc24 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 767
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010f45dbc8 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 890
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010f45eac4 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010f5e9e2c -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 248
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010f344d44 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 662
    22  QuartzCore                          0x0000000112fe7c80 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    23  QuartzCore                          0x0000000112fdc6ae _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    24  QuartzCore                          0x0000000112fdc52c _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    25  QuartzCore                          0x0000000112fd1104 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 284
    26  QuartzCore                          0x0000000112ffdf6c _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 508
    27  UIKit                               0x000000010f2c2676 _afterCACommitHandler + 174
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ebfca27 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ebfc997 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ebf247b __CFRunLoopRun + 1147
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ebf1d78 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    32  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000110eb7bca GraphicsServices + 52170
    33  UIKit                               0x000000010f29a79b UIApplicationMain + 171
    34  VIT Foody                           0x000000010e02621f main + 111
    35  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001150a1a05 libdyld.dylib + 10757
    36  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

The Trending view controller is as follows:
The view did load method i guess is the reason

```
[super viewDidLoad];
    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    refreshControl.tintColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Loading..."];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.mCollectionView addSubview:refreshControl];
    NSDictionary *username;
    save=@"trend";
    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"username"])
    {
        username = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"username"];
        NSLog(@"%@",[username description]);
        name.hidden=NO;
        name.text=[username valueForKey:@"first_name"];
    }
    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    arrayB = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self.mCollectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:save])
    {
        x=0;
        array=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:save];
        [self choose];
    }
    request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
        sta=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://vitcreativityclub.com/api/RESTAURANTAPI.php"];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sta]];
        [self requesting:request];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
```

Comment: Please show the contents of your `[TrendingController choose]` method.

Comment: I agree with JAL. The error message _[__NSCFArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object_ seems to indicate that your [TrendingController choose] is calling removeObjectAtIndex on an immutable NSArray. If you plan on removing objects from the array, you probably want to use **NSMutableArray** [https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSMutableArray]

Comment: I have Put up 
Please see